# pg_cron connection refused with postgres login

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron, psql, pg-hba.conf

I am trying to run a function periodically with pg_cron but every time it wants to execute it throws connection refused. the cron job is created using the postgres user.

pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    postgres        postgres        localhost               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I've tried adding a .pgpass file but, I don't know where to put it.
this is my machine version:
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: Is `pg_cron` run locally or remotely?  Which database are you trying to connect to as which user?

Comment: locally, i am trying to connect to database postgres as user postgres

Comment: And you're using the correct password?  Typically `.pgpass` lives in the user's `HOME` ... which in ubuntu (I assume debian will be similar?) would be `/var/lib/postgresql` ...

Comment: i tried putting it in /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass and /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/.pgpass both didn't work

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: i executed chmod 600 .pgpass

Comment: it works when i change the md5 to trust on the very first line in my config but then every one can just log in without password which is not ideal

Comment: Not everyone, just the postgres user. How did you set the password?

Comment: \password in the psql terminal

Comment: there's your problem. Unless postgres is set to encrypted passwords by default it stores them in the plain. Try`alter user postgres with encrypted password "password" ` from within a connection.

Comment: i still get connection failed

Comment: i changed this line `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust` and executed `UPDATE cron.job SET nodename = 'localhost'` and now it works

Comment: So pg_cron wasn't using local at all ... interesting.  You still may want to narrow down the permitted users and/or find out what the password authentication with MD5 didn't work.  Your *solution* leaves me with a stale taste in my mouth.